# Is it possible to play .3gp videos in browser on Android?

Tags: browser, video

I am not able to play **.3gp** videos with Google Chrome nor Firefox on Android. 
Chrome plays the video without image, only sound. And Firefox asks me directly to download the video.

I wonder if there is a way I can watch the video first in the browser, like a .mp4 video. Is it possible?

Comment: Which device/OS version do you have?

Comment: It's a LNMBBS tablet with Android 7. But I tried with other devices with Android 8 and it's the same thing.

Comment: 3GP is just a container format - what encoding is used by the video? May be your device just don't support the codec used by the specific video you used for testing.

Comment: The device plays the video in its gallery and other media players without problem. Codecs: MPEG-4 Video, AAC.